# Degeneracy locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles

In the paper [Non-Abelian Brill-Noether theory and Fano 3-folds](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9704015.pdf),
Proposition 1.2, part 3, the author uses a homomorphism of vector bundles $f:E\rightarrow F$ to produce a map $\ker f_x\otimes (\operatorname{coker} f_x)^\ast\rightarrow m_x/m_x^2$ of (I imagine) vector spaces over the ground field. I guess $m_x/m_x^2$ is fibre of the conormal sheaf. How is this map defined (he doesn't say that), and why is that part of the proposition true (he gives a reference, but that part of the proposition cannot be found in the reference)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose bases in $E_x$ and $F_x$ such that the first vectors span $\mathrm{ker} f_x$ and $\mathrm{im} f_x$ respectively. Then the matrix of $f_x$ can be written in the block form as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are matrices of functions on $X$, $B(x) = C(x) = D(x) = 0$, while $A(x)$ in invertible. Then the map you need is given by partial derivatives of the matrix $D$ at $x$. One can check that the result is independent of all choices.

EDIT. To get a coordinate free description of the map, let us consider a tangent vector at $x$, i.e., a morphism from $\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)$ to the variety in question that takes the closed point to $x$, pullback $f$ to $\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)$, and consider the composition
$$
(\mathrm{ker} f\vert_{\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)}) \to 
E\vert_{\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)} 
\stackrel{f\vert_{\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)}}\to 
F\vert_{\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)} \to 
(\mathrm{coker} f\vert_{\mathrm{Spec}(k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)}).
$$
It vanishes at the closed point, hence is divisible by $\epsilon$. After division you get a map $\mathrm{ker} f_x \to \mathrm{coker} f_x$. Since it is defined for each tangent vector, altogether you get a morphism
$$
(\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2)^* \otimes \mathrm{ker} f_x \to \mathrm{coker} f_x,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Many thanks! Is there an intrinsic description of the map? I thought that he doesn't define the map because it is some kind of canonical "obvious" map, but I didn't manage to write down such a map. Also, I guess the functions defining $A,B,C,D$ are only locally defined, in a neighborhood of $x$?

Comment: I added a description of the map. The functions, indeed, are defined in a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great answer. So $m/m^2$ is the cotangent space after all.. I'm not sure why the injectivity of this map at $x$ (where $f_x$ has maximal rank) should be equivalent to $x$ being a smooth point. This is why I thought that $m/m^2$ should be the fibre of the conormal sheaf, as smoothness is equivalent to the conormal sequence being left exact+locally free sheaf of differentials.